# Capistrano Error - Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I'm completely new to Capistrano and to Ruby, and I can't seem to get basic deployment set up.  Every time I run cap deploy:check I get the following error:

> servers: ["domain.com"]
>   connection failed for: me@domain.com (Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch: fingerprint 0c:de:d4:
>   1b:e9:64:83:3a:8b:d7:c3:42:98:5b:5d:8c does not match for "[domain.com]:22,[62.39.11.2]:22"
>   )

My deploy.db looks like this:

```
set :stages, %w(production staging)
set :default_stage, "staging"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "captest" # TODO
set :repository, "git@bitbucket.org:jy312/captest.git" # TODO
set :scm, :git
set :use_sudo, false

ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_exclude, [".git", ".DS_Store", ".gitignore", ".gitmodules"]
set :git_enable_submodules, 1
```

I've tried adding my local computers public key (id_rsa.pub) to the list of known_hosts on my server with no luck.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The destination server's fingerprint is not matching what is in your local `known_hosts` file. Remove the existing entry in your local `known_hosts` file.

You can also try fixing the issue by directly SSH'ing to the server instead of going through ruby since it's an SSH issue.

Comment: for extra context, on OSX location for know_hosts file is /Users/username/.ssh/known_hosts

Comment: if you could direclty ssh but still can't do it with capistrano, then just delete your `known_hosts` file. idk what things could go wrong with doing that though

Answer (score 9):

or just rewrite it by (change USERNAME and IP of your server):

```
$ ssh-keygen -f "/home/USERNAME/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 178.X.X.X
```

then enter the server

```
$ ssh user@178.X.X.X
```

and answer `yes`

retry deploy

good luck ;)

Answer (score 6):

Although not suitable for a production system, if you faced this problem while deploying to a local development environment you could consider telling Capistrano to ignore strict host-key verification.

deploy.rb

```
set :ssh_options, paranoid: false
```

https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/blob/e90551a4672587e294b47f824a401550f55184cc/lib/net/ssh.rb#L160

Comment: `paranoid: false` has been deprecated. Use `verify_host_key: :never` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Scenario : SSH from source machine to destination machine

if the above scenario throws Net::SSH::HostKeyMismatch , then  do below,

```
1) Login to source machine and sudo su <User>
2) ssh destination machine
3) in step2, HostKeyMismatch error will be displayed and also the known hosts location.

or

2) cd ~
3) cd .ssh
4) vim known_hosts
5) clear the content of the file and save and quit (using command - :wq)
```

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

deploy.rb

```
set :ssh_options, {verify_host_key: :never}
```